# Are the red strings used by Dexter a real thing?

Tags: realism, dexter

Dexter works as a blood splatter analyst for Miami Metro police. We often see him on a crime scene using red strings to represent the trajectory of the blood:

[image]
[image]

Is this a real thing done by blood splatter analysts or is it made up to make Dexter's job more "fancy" ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a real method for analyzing blood splatters.

> To find the area of convergence, investigators typically use string to
> create straight lines through the long axis of individual drops,
> following the angle of impact along a flat plane, for instance the
> floor or wall where the drops are found. Following the lines to where
> they intersect shows investigators where the victim was located when
> the drops were created.
>
> To find the area of origin, investigators use a similar method but
> also include the height calculations. This creates a 3-D estimate of
> the victim s location when the drops occurred. For example, if the
> area of origin is determined to be only two feet above the area of
> convergence on the floor, the analyst may presume the victim was
> either lying or sitting on the floor. If it is five feet above the
> convergence, the victim may have been standing. This analysis can be
> done using strings and a protractor, mathematical calculations or
> computer models.
>
> ( Source: [forensicsciencesimplified.org](http://www.forensicsciencesimplified.org/blood/how.html))

Refer [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloodstain_pattern_analysis#Point_and_area_of_convergence) for knowing more about string method.